# How to get original inserted text from input onkeyup textbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a small problem that is probably easy to fix, but I'm not that good yet. I'm trying to get the value of an input type=textbox. How do i get the original value entered?..not the dots?

```js
$(function() {
  var self = this;
  self.txtdata = "";
  $("body").on("keyup", "#txt1", function(e) {
    self.txtdata = self.txtdata + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    var txtbox = this;
    var dots = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $(txtbox).val().length; i++) {
      dots = dots + "●";
    }
    $(this).val(dots);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="tabname">Tabname:</label>
<input name="tabname" type="textbox" id="txt1" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Can you please share your relevant HTML part?

Comment: It might not be the best idea to get passwords this way for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/4gbog729/

```js
var text = "";
$('input[type="password"]').keypress(function(e){
 text += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="password">Password:</label> 
<input name="password" type="password" id="txt1" autocomplete="off">
```

Input type should be **Password** not textbox.

Solution without type as **password** here : https://jsfiddle.net/4gbog729/2/

```js
var text = "";
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e){
 text += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  var data = $(this).val();
  $(this).val( text.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]n*/g, '*'))
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="password">Password:</label> 
<input name="password" type="text" id="txt1" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I want to avoid input type Password but thanks for you answer.

Comment: Can't delete characters. Also, creating a log saves the characters as capital letters?

Comment: @Lugifah... Just have a look to the solution https://jsfiddle.net/4gbog729/3/ .  and let me know.

Comment: You will get the text value in keypress event. I am able to get the data in console in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4gbog729/4/

Comment: When the value " * " changed to "●" my console where i can see the entered data doesn't show anything, also the value from the first input isn't displayed.

Comment: I imagine that my console can only display * and not ● ... anyway, it still doesn't work. Do i need to do an AJAX call to get?

Comment: I don't think you a AJAX call is required. Rather my preference is input type as password. Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/4gbog729/5/

Comment: Still my server doesn't show up the value entered. I have 2 inputs on my html; 1st type=name  and 2nd type=text, when only 1st (type=name) is filled the server shows the value, when both are filled it doesn't return anything.

Comment: It posts the data after the dot change is made, not the first entered key.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to store the keycodes and later join them. Below is an updated code:

```js
$(function() {
  var self = this;
  var enteredText = [];
  self.txtdata = "";
  $("body").on("keyup", "#txt1", function(e) {
    enteredText.push(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
    self.txtdata = self.txtdata + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    var txtbox = this;
    var dots = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $(txtbox).val().length; i++) {
      dots = dots + "●";
    }
    $(this).val(dots);

    console.log(enteredText.join(''));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input name="password" type="textbox" id="txt1" autocomplete="off">
```

Sample/Pseudo AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'receive.php',
  data: {
    enteredText: enteredText
  },
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    // do something here after receiving success from server
  }
});
```

Comment: Good idea but the value is not posted back to the server. What i'm missing?

Comment: the AJAX call to the server. You need to do AJAX call to the server, passing the required parameters.

Comment: Thanks Milan. I have a simple .html page and that's it. I don't know how to do AJAX call to the server!